# How to get column value in a RenderPattern of a custom field?

Tags: xml, sharepoint, caml

I am trying to display the value of a column in the  tag of my custom field.

To get the column value, I can simply use:

```
<Column />
```

To get the value of another column, I can simply use:

```
<Column Name="InternalFieldName" />
```

The problem I am having is that I have the name of the column that I am interested in stored in a hidden field.

I can get the value of my hidden field using:

```
<Property Select="SomeColumnName" />
```

But how do I use that value in the column name attribute.

I want to do something like this:

```
<Column Name="<Property Select="SomeColumnName"/>" />
```

Any ideas????

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have to create a [custom field based on a calculated field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067623/can-i-create-my-own-formula-for-calculated-field-in-sharepoint-2010-using-c) in order to do this. There is no CAML syntax for what you required.